# How can i open React App on android device in the same local network?

Tags: reactjs

I created an app using the create-React-App. When I start the app it shows
You can now view the player in the browser.

Local: http://localhost:3000
On Your Network: http://192.168.1.37:3000

When I try to access this on my network from my android device (chrome for android) it shows `ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE`.

I cannot access the app from my network, from any device. I am using ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Your other devices need to be on the same network, e.g. if your system is on the Wi-Fi network XYZ, your android device should be on the same Wi-Fi network XYZ.

Comment: thanks for your solution but  my Pc and adroind device is already connected to the same Wi-Fi network

Answer (score 0):

Instead of prepending http , just use the ipV4 address (which you can find in your wifi properties in settings ) ie

***192.168.1.37:3000***

in your case and hit it in your android device while the server is running.